# How can I speed up xarray resample (much slower than pandas resample)

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray, resampling

Here is an MWE for resampling a time series in `xarray` vs. `pandas`. The `10Min` resample takes 6.8 seconds in `xarray` and 0.003 seconds in `pandas`. Is there some way to get the Pandas speed in xarray? Pandas resample seems to be independent of the period, while xarray scales with the period.

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import time

def make_ds(freq):
    size = 100000
    times = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=size, freq=freq)
    ds = xr.Dataset({
        'foo': xr.DataArray(
            data   = np.random.random(size),
            dims   = ['time'],
            coords = {'time': times}
        )})
    return ds

for f in ["1s", "1Min", "10Min"]:
    ds = make_ds(f)

    start = time.time()
    ds_r = ds.resample({'time':"1H"}).mean()
    print(f, 'xr', str(time.time() - start))

    start = time.time()
    ds_r = ds.to_dataframe().resample("1H").mean()
    print(f, 'pd', str(time.time() - start))
```

```
: 1s xr 0.040313720703125
: 1s pd 0.0033435821533203125
: 1Min xr 0.5757267475128174
: 1Min pd 0.0025794506072998047
: 10Min xr 6.798743486404419
: 10Min pd 0.0029947757720947266
```

Comment: For now, also filed as bug against `xarray`: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/4498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `xarray` [GH issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/4498) this is an implementation issue. The solution is to do the resampling (actually a `GroupBy`) in other code. My solution is to use the fast Pandas resample and then rebuild the xarray dataset:

```
df_h = ds.to_dataframe().resample("1H").mean()  # what we want (quickly), but in Pandas form
vals = [xr.DataArray(data=df_h[c], dims=['time'], coords={'time':df_h.index}, attrs=ds[c].attrs) for c in df_h.columns]
ds_h = xr.Dataset(dict(zip(df_h.columns,vals)), attrs=ds.attrs)
```